# How to speed up this PySpark code that's setting a flag based on column values being in a list

Tags: pyspark

I need to set a flag in a pyspark dataframe that's 1 if a column's value is in some list, and 0 otherwise:

```
ids = [email1, email2, ...]
df = df.withColumn('flag',when(col('id').isin(ids),lit(1.)).otherwise(lit(0.)))
```

But it's extremely slow.  I've tried using broadcast like so:

```
br_ids = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(ids)
df = df.withColumn('flag',when(col('id').isin(br_ids.value),lit(1.)).otherwise(lit(0.)))
```

But it's sill way too slow.  Any ideas as to how to speed it up?

Thank you!!

Comment: How many emails are on this list? How big is your DF? Where the code is running? cluster/local?

Comment: are you doing other transformations as well (while creating the `df` or before the final action on `df`)? the processing speed will depend on the data size, other transformations in the lineage, etc. as well.